# Disable form Submit based on validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core (v 2.0). There is a form with a few input text boxes and a submit button. I want to only allow a user to submit a valid form, so while the form is incomplete, I want the Submit button to be disabled.

Is there a way to easily do that using ASP.NET Core [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have set up client side validation correctly, then the form will not be submitted if its invalid (and the validation messages will be displayed). You do not 'disable' the submit button). You need to do some basic research - [Adding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation).

Comment: Stephen Muecke,  I know the form won't submit. But it's a common UX workflow -- the Submit button is disabled until the form is valid.  It's easy to do with other frameworks like Angular.

Comment: It is not a common UX workflow (at least not in mvc). And if you have set up client side validation, then 'final' validation is not triggered until you submit the form (which is then cancelled if the form is invalid and all messages are displayed), therefore you need something to trigger the submit, so disabling the submit button makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing built into ASP.NET MVC that does this for you automatically.  The UI pattern you are asking about would require JavaScript coding.

You could download and reference a validation library, like the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org). Then write some JavaScript in your page to check if the form is valid on [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) of each of the form inputs by checking `$("#myForm").valid()`, and only enable the submit button if the form is valid.

See attached snippet for an example.

```js
var $form = $("#myform");
var $submitbutton = $("#submitbutton");

$form.on("blur", "input", () => {
  if ($form.valid()) {
    $submitbutton.removeAttr("disabled");   
  } else {
    $submitbutton.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="text1" required />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="text2" required />
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" id="submitbutton" disabled>Submit Enabled When Valid</button>
</form>
```

Comment: asp.net-mvc automatically includes `jquery.validate.js` :) And since it adds `novalidate` to the `<form>`, the a `required` attribute makes no sense

Comment: Joe Wilson ok it works but is it any way to not trigger until you focus all items. I mean now we have 2 input first you focus and texted but after blur, it triggered the second textbox even it's in user filling path. Could you recommend me any solution for it?

Comment: $form.on("blur keyup change",  helped for me